# How do I get a button that is held down to change what it is doing after a power up ends?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

In the game I am trying to make. When I am holding my fire button and I pick up a power up SuperShot, it continues to fire my regular laser unless I release my fire button and press it again. The same thing happens again when the power up ends. I have researched and I cant seem to figure out a way to check on where the power up is active while holding the key down.

```
    private void Fire()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            if (SuperShotIsActive)
            {
                superShotFiringCoroutine = StartCoroutine(SuperShotFireContinuously());

            }
            else if (!SuperShotIsActive)
            {
                firingCoroutine = StartCoroutine(FireContinuously());
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
        {
            StopCoroutine(firingCoroutine);
            StopCoroutine(superShotFiringCoroutine);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to fix this by looking away from the button itself and into the code of the actual firing of the weapon.

```
//psuedocode-ish example. Just for the concept
//not necessarily the best idea to use a for loop but maybe it works for you.

FireContinuously()
{
    for(int foo = 0; foo < ammo; foo++)
    {
        if(!SuperShotIsActive)
        {
            //normal firing code you have goes here
        }
        else
        {
            //supershot code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

In `FireContinuously()` (which I assume is a loop of some sort) you can add a check before each shot to see if the player now has the powerup and the necessary logic to change to the appropriate `SuperShotFireContinuously()`. Do the opposite for `SuperShotFireContinuously()` to change to `FireContinuously()`.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I will give it a shot.